# Not seeing why my option will not sum up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to display a sum of all select option menu i have on a product page. I have simplified jsfiddle, like http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/8mnQR/184/ which works.

```
       <select name='anch1'>
        <option data-price="">----</option>
        <option data-price="10">10 ++</option>
        <option data-price="20">20 ++</option>
        <option data-price="30">30 ++</option>
        <option data-price="40">40 ++</option>
        <option data-price="50">50 ++</option>
    </select>

    <select name='anch2'>
        <option data-price="">----</option>
        <option data-price="10">10 ++</option>
        <option data-price="20">20 ++</option>
        <option data-price="30">30 ++</option>
        <option data-price="40">40 ++</option>
        <option data-price="50">50 ++</option>
    </select>

    <select name='anch3'>
        <option data-price="">----</option>
        <option data-price="10">10 ++</option>
        <option data-price="20">20 ++</option>
        <option data-price="30">30 ++</option>
        <option data-price="40">40 ++</option>
        <option data-price="50">50 ++</option>
    </select>

$('select').change(function(){
var sum = 0;
$('select :selected').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).data('price'));
});
 $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

But when i add a simplified product select menu, like so
http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/8mnQR/185/

The sum doesn't work correctly, only when i select both newly added select menus something is happening??

Do you see where i go wrong??

regards

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two jsfiddles.

Comment: *Doesn't work correctly?* What do you except with sample values and what is happening?

Comment: It would also help if you showed the code for the "simplified product select menu" so we wouldn't have to guess what it is.

Comment: The work exactly the same to me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8mnQR/189/  You were getting NaN as value

Comment: Huh? don't you guys see the SUM OF SELECTED OPTIONS disappearing and not showing the SUM??? Start by select an option of one of the two latest menu (http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/8mnQR/185/)

Comment: We didn't know that was the desired functionality. It would be equally possible that you wanted the sum to show only when all fields are filled. Note that both of your jsfiddles work *exactly the same*, including the one you say works correctly.

Comment: @Juhana, hmm i don't think so see Karthik answer. In my second fiddle the extra select menus didn't have the first option with a data-price attr. When i add the data-price attribute it seem to work as the first fiddle.

Comment: I don't think you understand. This is your first fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/8mnQR/184/ The code is **identical** with the second fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/8mnQR/185/

Comment: Even Karthik says so in his answer.

Comment: aha, i see now i have saved 184 the same as 185. jsfiddle 184 was like http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/8mnQR/193/. my bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data-price of last 2 select menu's are not set, hence .each function add's (0+0+0+NAN+NAN) = "NaN"

set "data-price" for the newly added select to "" or "0"

i.e 
change

```
<option>---</option>
```

to

```
<option data-price="">---</option>
```

just a note... both your fiddle works the same way.. both have the same issue.

Comment: tx Karthik, i totally overlooked the data-price attribute not being set for the first option